# c# Struggling to read ValueMember for item x from checkListBox

Tags: c#, linq, checklistbox

I have a checkedListBox that has been populated from a Linq To SQL query (I do not want to bound the list directly to the Linq query).

I populate it with:

```
var selected = from c in dc.Personnel
select new { Item = c.PersonnelID, Description = c.FirstName + " " + c.Surname };

        foreach (var item in selected)
            myList.Items.Add(item.Item, item.Description);

        myList.DisplayMember = "Description";
        myList.ValueMember = "Item";
```

Now I want to retrieve the ValueMember at position x like:

```
myList.GetItem(0).ValueMember
```

Obviously that is not correct, but I'm not sure what the correct method is.  Statement above have compile error that `'object does not contain definition for ValueMember'`.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is use `myList.GetItem(0)`.  Since you've set your `myList.ValueMember` ahead of time, it will return the value stored in the `Item` property of the bound item, i.e. `item.Item`.

`ValueMember` is not the value itself, it's the name of the "member", i.e. the property, on the bound objects that will represent the values contained in the list.

Here is the doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yx132k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: myList.GetItem(0) returns the following.
Surely there should be a method to just get the PersonnelID?
{0000001000: James Smith                      }
    base: {0000001000: James Smith                      }
    CheckState: Unchecked
    Description: "James Smith                      "
    Enabled: true